# Type error 'str' object is not callable Python

Tags: python

```
for i in range(len(msg)):
        if ord(msg[i]) == 32: 
            encryptedMessage += chr(ord(msg[i])) 
            
        elif ord(msg[i]) + key > 122:
            temp = (ord(msg[i]) + key) - 122
            encryptedMessage += chr(96+temp)
             
        elif (ord(msg[i]) + key > 90) and (ord(msg([i]) < 96)):
            temp = (ord(msg[i]) + key) - 90
            encryptedMessage += chr(64+temp) 
                                          
        else:
            encryptedMessage += chr(ord(msg([i]) + key))
```

Updated code:

```
def encrypt():
    print("Heres our Caeser Cipher Encryption program.\n")
    msg = input("Enter the message you would like to encrypt: ").strip()
    print()
    key = int(input("Enter key to encrypt, a number 0-25: ")) #based on 26 letters in the alphabet

    encryptedMessage = ""

    for ch in msg:
        if ord(ch) == 32: 
            encryptedMessage += chr(ord(ch)) 
            
        elif ord(ch) + key > 122:
            temp = (ord(ch) + key) - 122
            encryptedMessage += chr(96+temp)
             
        elif (ord(ch) + key > 90) and (ord(ch) < 96):
            temp = (ord(ch) + key) - 90
            encryptedMessage += chr(64+temp) 
                                          
        else:
            encryptedMessage += chr(ord(ch) + key)
                                    
        print("\nEncrypting your message...\n")
        sleep(2) # give an appearance of doing something complicated
        print("Stand by, almost finished...\n")
        sleep(2) # more of the same
        print("Your encrypted message is:\n")
        print(encryptedMessage)
```

I am not receiving any errors anymore but the coding doesn't work how I want it to, I made this as an encryption program that is supposed to print code based on what text and shift key the user inputs. However the program only prints one letter.

Comment: What is the error you get? Could you post that as well in your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the second elif condition and the else line, you have round brackets around the square-bracket index into the string msg, which is likely the problem. Try it like this:

```
for i in range(len(msg)):
        if ord(msg[i]) == 32: 
            encryptedMessage += chr(ord(msg[i])) 
            
        elif ord(msg[i]) + key > 122:
            temp = (ord(msg[i]) + key) - 122
            encryptedMessage += chr(96+temp)
             
        elif (ord(msg[i]) + key > 90) and (ord(msg[i]) < 96):
            temp = (ord(msg[i]) + key) - 90
            encryptedMessage += chr(64+temp) 
                                          
        else:
            encryptedMessage += chr(ord(msg[i]) + key)
```

It might be simpler and clearer to just iterate over msg without using range, something like this:

```
for ch in msg:
```

Then, wherever you have msg[i] you can refer instead to ch - less nesty brackets and maybe a bit more readable.Here's what the code would look like then:

```
for ch in msg:
        if ord(ch) == 32: 
            encryptedMessage += chr(ord(ch)) 
            
        elif ord(ch) + key > 122:
            temp = (ord(ch) + key) - 122
            encryptedMessage += chr(96+temp)
             
        elif (ord(ch) + key > 90) and (ord(ch) < 96):
            temp = (ord(ch) + key) - 90
            encryptedMessage += chr(64+temp) 
                                          
        else:
            encryptedMessage += chr(ord(ch) + key)
```

Here's a working example which you should be able to just copy, paste and run:

```
msg = input("Message: ")
key = 13

encryptedMessage = ""
for ch in msg:
        if ord(ch) == 32: 
            encryptedMessage += ch
            
        elif ord(ch) + key > 122:
            temp = (ord(ch) + key) - 122
            encryptedMessage += chr(96+temp)
             
        elif (ord(ch) + key > 90) and (ord(ch) < 96):
            temp = (ord(ch) + key) - 90
            encryptedMessage += chr(64+temp) 
                                          
        else:
            encryptedMessage += chr(ord(ch) + key)


print(encryptedMessage)
```

Comment: Thank you so much I don't get errors anymore but now it turns out that my code isn't actually doing what I want it to do.. whoops, its meant to encrypt a message using the specific text and shift the user inputs like a Caeser Cipher program yet it only prints one letter at the end instead of the encrypted message

Comment: Hmm... It seems to work for me. I added the input, a key and a print at the end - I'll edit the answer to add a "working example" that you can try.

Comment: It works now oh my I'm not sure what happened there thank you so much again